# how to get images included in a gallery - included in an article

Tags: php, mysql

three tables - `articles`, `galleries`, `images`.

`articles` has a column `gallery` (`integer` - `id` of included gallery)

`galleries` has a column `images` (`csv string` - `ids` of included images)

`images` has `id` and `src` columns.

Now I need to get `src of images` -> included in a `gallery` -> included in an `article`.

I firstly select `gallery id` from the table `articles`

Then - using the given `gallery id` - select `images ids` from the table `galleries`

Then using the given `images-ids` - select the `sources of images` from the table `images`.

This scenario is tedious, requires a lot lot of coding.

Is there any shorter, easier way?

I cannot write `img sources` or `img ids` directly inside `articles` because need to get changes inside `articles` automatically - when a change inside `galleries` or `images` is done.

Any help?

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: @Strawberry, I see the problem with `csv` inside a column, but replacign the `csv` with a separate row for each element - `doesn't solve` the problem with three tables as described in my post. So your link is `related` or `helping` but the question is not duplicated.

Comment: The point really is that MySQL is a relational database management system. If you don't want to use relational data, that's fine, but then don't use (or why bother with) a relational database management system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JOIN`

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.id, a.column_name,c.sources FROM articles a,galleries b,images c WHERE a.id = b.id and b.id = c.id';

  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  // your desire calculation

  } else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
```